# AHK using Escape<Chars>Escape example

Tags: autohotkey

How can I use Escape as part of my AHK script. I would like to send the following hotkey combo:

> Press and Release Escape key

> Type m

> Type u

> Press and Release Escape key again

to print Greek letter μ

I am trying to be consistent w/ Wolfram Mathematica's way of inserting letters/symbols using Escape character.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is very doable with AHK.
What you're looking for, is a [hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm).

Because of the usage of the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in your hotstring, first I'll be showing the usage of the modern `Hotstring()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotstring.htm)</sup> function instead of the traditional `::btw::by the way` hotstring syntax.

```
esc := Chr(0x1B) ;27

Hotstring(":*?B0C:" esc "mu" esc, "{BS 2}μ")
Hotstring(":*?B0C:" esc "alpha" esc, "{BS 5}α")
Hotstring(":*?B0C:" esc "Alpha" esc, "{BS 5}Α")
;...
```

So, first we're storing the string representation of the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in a variable named `esc` with `Chr()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Chr.htm)</sup>.
The character code for <kbd>Esc</kbd> is 27. You could look this up e.g. the official Unicode character name list (available in [pdf](https://unicode.org/Public/14.0.0/charts/CodeCharts.pdf) and [txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt)), or some website which makes filtering easier, such as https://unicodelookup.com/.

Optionally, you could also just keep the <kbd>Esc</kbd> character there in its string representation. It would work just fine, and will even look just fine if your editor is good enough to display the character properly.
You can also use the traditional way of specifying a hotstring if you do so.
The below two lines are functionally indentical:
`Hotstring(":*?B0C:mu", "{BS 2}μ")`
`:*?B0C:mu::{BS 2}μ`
EDIT: Stack Overflow doesn't seem to display the <kbd>Esc</kbd> characters at all, at least not on my end. But the above two lines of codes should include the <kbd>Esc</kbd> character like seen in the screenshot below.
[image: Editor screenshot]

Then about the hotstring itself.
I'm guessing you'll want `*?B0C`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options)</sup> as options for the hotstring, but you can choose whatever fits your needs:

- `*` so an ending character is not required to trigger the hotstring.
- `?` so the hotstring can be trigger even is it inside another word.
- `B0` so automatic backspacing is not done.
  This is a must, because for e.g. the `mu` hotstring, AHK will backspace **four** times, since the hotstring is four characters long, but the <kbd>Esc</kbd> keys don't actually produce input and you only want to backspace **twice**.
- `C` to make the hotstring case sensitive.

Then `{BS 2}`<sup>([docs1](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#keynames), [docs2](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Repeating_or_Holding_Down_a_Key))</sup> means to press backspace twice.

> Be sure to note that you'll need to save your script file an appropriate encoding to not lose the Greek letters.

UTF-8 is be good enough to cover all Greek letters.
Optionally, you could again use `Chr()` to specify the Greek letters so there's no need to worry about encoding.
E.g. `"{BS 5}" Chr(0x3B1)` instead of `"{BS 5}α"`

---

And that's pretty much it.
You can repeat that line for each hotstring you need.

Also, since I'm bored, here's something cooler you can use to create *any* <kbd>Esc</kbd> wrapped hotstring:

```
ReplacementMap := CSobj()
ReplacementMap["alpha"] := Chr(0x3B1) ;Chr() notation not mandatory
ReplacementMap["Alpha"] := Chr(0x391)
ReplacementMap["mu"] := Chr(0x3BC)
ReplacementMap["Mu"] := Chr(0x39C)
ReplacementMap["dog"] := Chr(0x1F415) ;
ReplacementMap["cat"] := Chr(0x1F408) ;
ReplacementMap["btw"] := "by the way"
;...


for hotstring, replacement in ReplacementMap
    Hotstring(":*?B0CX:" Chr(0x1B) hotstring Chr(0x1B), Func("EscHotstringReplacement").Bind(StrLen(hotstring), replacement))

return

EscHotstringReplacement(BackspaceCount, Replacement)
{
    SendInput, % "{BS " BackspaceCount "}" Replacement
}

CSobj() {
   static base := object("_NewEnum","__NewEnum", "Next","__Next", "__Set","__Setter", "__Get","__Getter", "__Call","__Caller")
   return, object("__sd_obj__", ComObjCreate("Scripting.Dictionary"), "base", base)
}
   __Getter(self, key) {
      return, self.__sd_obj__.item("" key)
   }
   __Setter(self, key, value) {
      self.__sd_obj__.item("" key) := value
      return, false
   }
   __NewEnum(self) {
      return, self
   }
   __Next(self, ByRef key = "", ByRef val = "") {
      static Enum
      if not Enum
         Enum := self.__sd_obj__._NewEnum
      if Not Enum[key], val:=self[key]
         return, Enum:=false
      return, true
   }
   __Caller(self, name) {
      if (name = "count")
         return, self.__sd_obj__.count
   }
```

I won't document this thoroughly, but basically `CSobj()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=29198)</sup> for a case sensitive key-value pair object, `X` hotstring option<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#X)</sup> to execute and a bound function object<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Func.htm#Bind)</sup> to execute.